# Kotlin: Deserialize JSON to a different SerializedName

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I'm migrating a Kotlin code from using a backend to use a new one.
I'm having an issue in the next situation:

The old backend would return a JSON response-body with next schema:

`{code: "...", message: "...", data: "{"id": ..., "name": ..., ...}"}`.

But the new backend returns only

If not-success: `{code: "...", message: "..."}`.

If success or `{"id": "...", "name": "...", ...}`

This should be mapped to a class ResponseBody.

```
data class ResponseBody<T>(
@SerializedName(value: "code") val responseCode: Int,
@SerializedName(value: "message") val message: Int,
@SerializedName(value: "data") val data: T?)
)
```

Which is inside a class Data Wrapper:

```
data class DataWrapper<T>(
val responseBody: ResponseBody<T>?,
val throwable: Throwable?)
)
```

I have a method execute() where data mapping should happen after receiving response from backend.

```
    fun <T> execute(observable: Single<ResponseBody<T>>): Single<DataWrapper<T>> {
       return observable
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .map {t -> DataWrapper(t, null)}
           .onErrorReturn {t -> DataWrapper(null, t)}
           .map {
              (...)
           }
     }
```

So, my problem is that I'm not able to serialize in the case of success the response-body I get

```
{"id": "...", "name": "...", ...}
```

to the 'data' property in ResponseBody. I know that the problem is the fact that that response-body is not encapsulated in a {"data": ...} like it was in the old backend so the serialization doesn't work. Is there a dirty fix for this? Any suggestion?

I want to get, in the case of success, the response-body to be saved in the 'data' property of the ResponseBody class.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wait, are you manually deserializing the JSON response instead of using a library like Moshi?